# Angular error Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to convert a javascript version of the [following slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto) to be used in Typescript language, but I ran into an issue:

I get an error that says:

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

It looks like it does not accept `slides[this.selectedindex - 1].style.display` in typescript. So I added `(<HtmlElement>...)` but it does not work.

I have implemented the following code:

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbCarousel, NgbSlideEvent, NgbSlideEventSource } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],

})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  role: Number;
  public selectedindex: number = 0;
  public images = ['../../assets/images/healthimage1.png', '../../assets/images/healthimage2.jpg', '../../assets/images/healthimage3.jpg'];
  
  selectImage(index: number) {
    console.log("Index: " + index);
    this.selectedindex = index;
    console.log("Selected Index: " + this.selectedindex);
  }

  showSlides() {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      (<HTMLElement>slides[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
    this.selectedindex++;
    if (this.selectedindex > slides.length) { this.selectedindex = 1 }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    (<HTMLElement>slides[this.selectedindex - 1]).style.display = "block";
    dots[this.selectedindex - 1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(this.showSlides, 2000);
  }


  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
    this.role = 1;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.showSlides();
  }

}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="images">
  <div class="mySlides slideshow-container">
      <img *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index" 
          [src]="image" 
          [ngClass]="{'image-active': selectedindex == i}">  

      <div style="text-align:center; display:inline-block;"  *ngFor="let dot of images; let i=index">
          <span class="dot" 
              (click)="selectImage(i)"
              [ngClass]="{'active': selectedindex == i}">
          </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.slideshow-container img{
  display: none;
}

.slideshow-container img.image-active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

/* The dots/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working demo in this [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6g9hjv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You need to reference html element in angular in order to dom manipulation in angular.

html template is

```
<ng-container>
<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
<p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">

    <div #slides class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6027869/pexels-photo-6027869.jpeg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
    </div>

    <div #slides class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3889926/pexels-photo-3889926.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
    </div>

    <div #slides class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6027869/pexels-photo-6027869.jpeg" style="width:100%">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
    </div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <span #dot class="dot"></span>
    <span #dot class="dot"></span>
    <span #dot class="dot"></span>
</div>
</ng-container>
```

above #slides and #dots are template reference variable. We are using @ViewChildren() to get more than one slides and dots element reference from component.ts file

**component.ts file**

```
slidesIndex = 0;
@ViewChildren("slides") slides: QueryList<ElementRef>;
@ViewChildren("dot") dots: QueryList<ElementRef>;
slider$;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.showSlides();
}

showSlides() {
  this.slides.forEach(
   (slidesDiv: ElementRef) =>
     (slidesDiv.nativeElement.style.display = "none")
   );
this.slidesIndex += 1;

if (this.slidesIndex > this.slides.length) {
  this.slidesIndex = 1;
}
this.dots.forEach(
  dotsDiv =>
    (dotsDiv.nativeElement.className = dotsDiv.nativeElement.className.replace(
      " active",
      ""
    ))
);
this.slides.toArray()[this.slidesIndex - 1].nativeElement.style.display =
  "block";
this.dots.toArray()[this.slidesIndex - 1].nativeElement.className +=
  " active";
setTimeout(() => {
  this.showSlides();
}, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Wow this works great, the only catch is that some of this code I have never seen before. You removed `implements OnInit` and used `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`. I noticed that it threw me an error for the `forEach` loop function with `ngOnInit`. Not really sure if `slider$;` does anything.

Comment: We are using `@ViewChildren()`.. To get reference of this is only available in `ngAfterViewOnit()`.  This event fires only after component view is rendered by angular and is available inside component file. In ngOnOnit() we can not get any view elements inside component.

Comment: If you have any further queries, feel free to connect to me on email : grdtechlab@gmail.com .

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with viewChild and not document.getElementByClassName.

So, give and id in the html to your slide section.

```
 <div class="mySlides slideshow-container" id="idSlides">
```

In your angular component, you define slides as

```
@ViewChild('idSlides', { static: false })
    slides: Slides;
```

I think, the value of slides shouldn't be null or undefined.

Document.getElementById is used for Javascript and not angular

Answer (score 0):

After migrating from Angular 12 to 13, I had similar error cos we were using custom-webpack in angular.json. Removing and using default build configuration helped.

`"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",`
to

`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",`

for example

Answer (score 0):

Also I got this error when I used PrimeNG frozen dataTable controller with resizableColumns="true" as following

```
<p-dataTable resizableColumns="true" frozenWidth="700px" unfrozenWidth="700px" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500px">
<p-column frozen="true" [style]="{'width':'100px'}" field="Name" header="Name"></p-column>
```

**and I fixed it by removing resizableColumns="true"**